# Redirect with two parameter?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Why i can't make redirect with two parameter in Symfony 1.4?

```
$this->redirect('news/edit?id='.$news->getId() . '&test='.$news->getTest());
```

This redirect me to **http://mysite.com/news/edit/id/3** instead of to:

**http://mysite.com/news/edit/id/3/test/4**

How can i  make redirect with two parameter?

Comment: it works for me this way :S maybe this have something to do with your routing system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution should work just fine.

But check if `$news->getTest()` isn't empty and check if you're not having a routing that makes problems.

Alternatively you can give this a try:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParameter('id', $news->getId());
$this->getRequest()->setParameter('test', $news->getTest());
$this->forward('news', 'edit');
```

Answer (score 1):

redirect expecst a url, you can build this url with the url helper methods like

```
url_for2($routeName, $params = array());
```

where params is an associative array.